# date offset by 1 in docusaurus blog

Tags: docusaurus

I am using docusaurus v2 and created a blog file with the name containing the date I want it to be shown as the post date. However, the date in the generated blog is off by 1 day. Is this something to do with UTC vs local time? How do I make sure the date I give in the file name is the date it displays?

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet resolved. There is an open issue here: https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/4881

It looks like it's related timezone conversion between UTC and local. A few people have posted temporary workarounds.